# Mapquest Embed javascript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, com, embed, mapquest

I'm trying to use a mapquest map inside an embedded browser object (IE on Windows desktop)

If I put the embed link directly into the browser eg http://www.mapquest.com/embed?q=SW1Y%206QT it works but if I send it to the browser via COM using the Navigate method then I get this error

Line: 1
Char: 72744656
Error: 'JSON' is undefined
Code: 0
URL: http://dm.advertising.com/ids/916f352e-1af6-43dd-bc12-239421d8b718

I can click OK and the map is drawn with a pin and I can move about it but I don't know how to get rid of this error

Has anyone else seen this ?

Comment: can you please share some code?

Comment: There isn't really any code to post. This is not a VB.NET project but if you start one, drag on a button and web browser control and then in the click of the button do this 
`Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.mapquest.com/embed?q=SW1Y%206QT")

    End Sub

End Class`

You will get errors. Thanks